# Dynamically generate url and page content from multiple JSON files using node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, loops

I was trying to generate multiple url/pages using node.js express. I have multiple (currently 10 but the number may change) urls stored in one JSON file and I have another 10 (bound to change) JSON files that contain the information for each url respectively.

Currently I am using request-json to get the JSON file from a local server. However, my codes only allow me to create the very last url and its content in the loop

```
client.get("url1", function(error, response, body){                
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        var urlName = body.row[i];
        client.get("url2" + urlName, function(error, response, body) {
            app.get('/'+ urlName, function (req, res){ 
                res.send(body);     
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: It's because there is a `async` call in `for` loop.

Comment: I've added an answer, what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It's because there is a `async` call in `for` loop. You are saying use current value of `i` or `urlName` in a `async` function `app.get`.

And `app.get` will be called when `client.get` will finished.

So when it will be called your `for` loop will be finished so it will call with latest value of `i/urlName` which will be your last row `i=10`. So it goes for that.

try this:-

```
var performCurrentOperation = function(i,body){
    var urlName = body.row[i];
    client.get("url2" + urlName, function(error, response, body) {
        app.get('/'+ urlName, function (req, res){ 
            res.send(body);     
        });
    });
}

client.get("url1", function(error, response, body){                
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        performCurrentOperation(i,body);
    }
});
```

Basically here what I am doing I've bind a function with that value of `i` so it should perform operation on current value of `i`.